# Grails Data Service transaction and save.flush Question

Tags: grails

I am saving different information to the database inside a transaction.

For example:

```
@transactional
def saveMyBook() {
   def author = new Author()
   def book = new Book()
   def pricing = new Pricing()

   author.save()
   book.save()
   pricing.save()
}
```

I want the author to be saved to the database right away.  I change the author.save() to author.save(flush:true)

```
@transactional
def saveMyBook() {

   ...

   author.save(flush:true)
   book.save()
   pricing.save()
}
```

Is author.save(flush:true) still inside the transaction?

If this transaction fails, will grails also roll back this author?

If author.save(flush:true) is still inside the transaction, what code do I need to type so, author.save(flush:true) is standalone not in a transaction?  I want to mean that if the transaction fails, I still want this author saved to the database.

Thanks!

Comment: add `throw new Exception()` as the last line and check it on your own. btw different Grails versions may behave differently

Comment: I don't understand why I need to force this action to throw an exception.  What am I checking?

Comment: exceptions are how rollbacks are triggered... he's asking you to try it and see what gets saved, etc.

Comment: Ooooh!  Thanks for clarifying.  Silly me.